# Titanium File Association in Gallery

Tags: file, gallery, titanium, file-association, titanium-mobile

I want to develop an app in Titanium. When I am in the gallery and select the pictures, I would like my app to appear in the Share list, and get the photos. Is this omehow possible?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what share list? Android or iOS?

Answer (score 0):

See [Android Intent Filters](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Android+Intent+Filters) on the Appcelerator wiki for an example of how to get your app in the 'share' menu on Android.